# X-axis scale is not in sync with graph while zoom in/out and panning using chartjs/chartjs-zoom plugins

Tags: typescript, angular7, chartjs-plugin-zoom

charjs-zoom-plugin version: 0.7.7 and chartjs-2.9.2

while doing zoom in/out(using the scroll bar) and panning(mouse drag), the x-axis scale is scaling the opposite direction as compared to the graph moving direction.
any idea why it behaves like this. any help or suggestions helps.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ostGr.jpg)